# ¿Cómo contar registros MySQL con input type radio HTML?

Tags: php, html, mysql, html5

Tengo una db llamada ***miembros*** a la me gustaría contabilizar los datos de las  columnas llamadas ***'estado'*** y ***'categoria'*** a través de un input tipo radio en HTML cuando éstos son presionados.

Si los valores que guarda la primera columna pueden ser "s,c,v,d", y la segunda "c,d,j,t,a", ¿cómo hago para que al dar clic en uno de los radio me arroje el total de los registros de esa entidad en el campo destinado para ello?

Lo que tengo hasta el momento es eso:

¿Cómo hago para contabili si tieno un formulario como el siguiente?

```
<?php
include("conexion.php");

$estado = $conexion->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM miembros WHERE 'estado'='c'");
?>

<h3>CONTABILIZAR DATOS</h3>
        <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Informacion: </legend>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Estado:</legend>
                            <input type="radio" name="estado" value="s" id="e_s"> Soltero
                            <input type="radio" name="estado" value="c" id="e_c"> Casado
                            <input type="radio" name="estado" value="v" id="e_v"> Viudo
                            <input type="radio" name="estado" value="d" id="e_d"> Separado<br><br>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Categoria:</legend>
                            <input type="radio" name="categoria" value="c" id="tag_c"> Caballero
                            <input type="radio" name="categoria" value="d" id="tag_d"> Dama
                            <input type="radio" name="categoria" value="j" id="tag_j"> Joven
                            <input type="radio" name="categoria" value="t" id="tag_t"> Adolescente
                            <input type="radio" name="categoria" value="a" id="tag_a"> Anciano<br>
                    </fieldset>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>
                <legend>Resultado: </legend>
                    <?php echo "Resultado va aqui" ?>
                </fieldset>

            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más basico sería recargar la pantalla al cambiar las opciones y al volver a cargar  verificamos que parámetos enviamos y generamos un filtrado de la consulta acorde.

He quitado `enctype="multipart/form-data"` pues no hace falta, solo si vas a adjuntar algun fichero.

Además añadí:

- un evento `click` en los `inputs` para recagar nada más pulsar.
- una opción `TODOS` para no aplicar filtro.
- lo necesario para dejar marcada la opción escogida.

El código resultate sería:

```
<?php

include("conexion.php");

$filtro = ' WHERE 1 ';
if (!empty($_POST['estado'])) {
    $filtro .= " AND estado = '{$_POST['estado']}' ";
}
if (!empty($_POST['categoria'])) {
    $filtro .= " AND categoria = '{$_POST['categoria']}' ";
}

$consulta = $conexion->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM miembros $filtro ");
$resultado = $consulta->fetch_object();

?>

<h3>CONTABILIZAR DATOS</h3>
        <form action="" method="POST">

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Informacion: </legend>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Estado:</legend>
                            <input <?=$_POST['estado']=='s'?' checked ':''?> type="radio" name="estado" value="s" id="e_s" onclick="this.form.submit()"> Soltero
                            <input <?=$_POST['estado']=='c'?' checked ':''?> type="radio" name="estado" value="c" id="e_c" onclick="this.form.submit()"> Casado
                            <input <?=$_POST['estado']=='v'?' checked ':''?> type="radio" name="estado" value="v" id="e_v" onclick="this.form.submit()"> Viudo
                            <input <?=$_POST['estado']=='d'?' checked ':''?> type="radio" name="estado" value="d" id="e_d" onclick="this.form.submit()"> Separado<br><br>
                            <input <?=$_POST['estado']==''?'  checked ':''?> type="radio" name="estado" value=""  onclick="this.form.submit()"> TODOS <br><br>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Categoria:</legend>
                            <input <?=$_POST['categoria']=='c'?' checked ':''?> type="radio" name="categoria" value="c" id="tag_c" onclick="this.form.submit()"> Caballero
                            <input <?=$_POST['categoria']=='d'?' checked ':''?> type="radio" name="categoria" value="d" id="tag_d" onclick="this.form.submit()"> Dama
                            <input <?=$_POST['categoria']=='j'?' checked ':''?> type="radio" name="categoria" value="j" id="tag_j" onclick="this.form.submit()"> Joven
                            <input <?=$_POST['categoria']=='t'?' checked ':''?> type="radio" name="categoria" value="t" id="tag_t" onclick="this.form.submit()"> Adolescente
                            <input <?=$_POST['categoria']=='a'?' checked ':''?> type="radio" name="categoria" value="a" id="tag_a" onclick="this.form.submit()"> Anciano<br>
                            <input <?=$_POST['categoria']==''?'  checked ':''?> type="radio" name="categoria" value="" onclick="this.form.submit()"> TODOS <br>
                    </fieldset>
                </fieldset>


            </form>

    <div>
    <label>Resultado: </label>
        <?php echo $resultado->total ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ahora me doy cuenta que necesito adicionar una tabla para que me muestre al menos los nombres y apellidos del radio selecionado. Alguna idea?

Comment: Tienes todo lo necesario ahí  ;)  Añade otra consulta o cambia la actual para que te devuelva los datos que necesites, prueba, practica y cuando tengas una duda concreta abre otra pregunta lo más detallada posible. Ánimo.

Answer (score 0):

Una buena solución seria con Ajax :

```
<!--tienes que añadir en el head la libreria jquery y el javascript tal cual lo ves aqui-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready (function () {

    $("input:radio[value=c]").click(function () 
    {
        //aqui recoges el valor del input que ya se sabe que es c
        estado =  $("input:radio[value=c]").val();
          $.ajax({

              //la consulta se hace en un fichero aparte ya no hace falta que pongas el include('conexion.php')
                    url: 'conexion.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {estado: estado},

                    success: function(result)
                    {

                    contenedor = document.getElementsByTagName('fieldset')[3];

                    texto = document.createTextNode(result);

                    contenedor.appendChild(texto);

                    //para que nos devuelva el resultado deseado en la consulta
                    //que haces en el fichero conexion.php  tienes que 
                    // convertirla en objeto json de esta forma
                    //$estado = $conexion->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM miembros WHERE 'estado'='c'");
                    //echo json_encode($estado);
                    // y ya con esto se produce la magia.



                    }


                 });


    });
});



</script>
```

Comment: ¿solucionaste tu pregunta ? , espero haberte ayudado, para cualquier cosa puedes comentarme y estaré encantado de contestarle.